# What is the maximum number of parameters for a method (WebApi ? )

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have this method in WebApi

```
[IHttpActionResult]
[Get]
public void GetSome(P1, P2 ....... Pn)
{
   ...///
}
```

Just curious:

Any ideas, what is the maximum number of parameters allowed by WebApi for this method ?

Comment: is this going to get a spec-hunt or has this a real-world-usage?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair: Just curious:) No impact

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You mean technically or practically? :p

The C# method parameter limit is 65,535. Most browsers only support an URL of 2000 to 4000 characters. Depending on the consumer of your API, there might be some restrictions there as well.

But most importantly: what are you trying to do? Seriously?

You're creating an API, simple methods that are easy to understand should be your main goal. I'm not sure a method with 65000 parameters would be anywhere near simple.

To me this sounds like step 1 of a walk down "OMG kill this code" lane :)

Comment: Just being curious :) My project involves atmost 4-5 parameters :)

Answer (score 3):

There are few similar `Q & A` around `Internet` and `Stack overflow`. Which is asked to know the `C# Method maximum number of parameters`. The same will be applicable in your case as well.

**Cases:**

- A .net application containing a method with `16383` parameters can be
  compiled, ran, and called (!)
- A .net application containing `16384` or more parameters can be
  compiled, but running such a program throws an unstated exception.
- A .net application containing 50000 parameters can also be compiled,
  but attempting to run such an application results in a
  `StackOverflowException` being thrown.
- Attempting to compile a .net application containing 100000 parameters
  or more results in `csc.exe` giving a compile-time error, `stating
  that the resulting expression is too long or complex to handle`.

**Note:**

- Those numbers depend on the architecture of the `operating system`
  and the memory of the `computer`.
- From Browser side it may vary. It may be allow less or more than this
  count.

**Similar Q & A**:

[C# Method Maximum Number of Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658883/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-parameters-that-a-c-sharp-method-can-be-defined-as)

[Acceptable Parameters Count for a C# Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431932/how-many-parameters-in-c-sharp-method-are-acceptable)

> Passing required and less number of parameters to the Method will be the best coding
>   practice.